# Rails 4 - selectively display table fields in partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to display two different tabular representations of my `Job` model with different fields displayed in each table:

**dashboard.html.erb**

```
...
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Job #</th>
      <th>Job Name</th>
      <th>Due Date</th>
      <th>Progress</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= render @jobs_due_soon %> <!-- version 1 -->
  </tbody>
</table>

...

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Job #</th>
      <th>Job Name</th>
      <th>Cut At</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= render @jobs_completed %> <!-- version 2 -->
  </tbody>
</table>
...
```

**_job.html.erb** version 1

```
<tr>
  <td><%= job.number %></td>
  <td><%= job.name %></td>
  <td><%= job.due_date %></td>
  <td><%= job.progress %></td>
</tr>
```

**_job.html.erb** version 2

```
<tr>
  <td><%= job.number %></td>
  <td><%= job.name %></td>
  <td><%= job.cut_at %></td>
</tr>
```

What is the best way to achieve this? I could have two different partials and call each one depending on which table I am displaying. I could alternatively pass in a local variable specifying version 1 or 2. However, neither of these options feels like the right way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could do this, depending on how you want to separate out the responsibilities. I'm not familiar with your codebase, so the class and variable names are just for getting the general idea.

## Place Report Logic into the Job Model:

```
# job.rb
# ------

  def Job.jobs_due_soon
    # logic for generating the data needed for your jobs due soon table
  end

  def Job.jobs_completed
    # logic for generating the data needed for your jobs completed table
  end


# jobs_controller.rb
# ------------------

  def dashboard
    @jobs_due_soon = Job.jobs_due_soon
    @jobs_completed = Job.jobs_completed
    render :dashboard
  end


# dashboard.html.erb
# ------------------

  <%= render 'table', data: @jobs_due_soon %>
  <%= render 'table', data: @jobs_completed %>


# _table.html.erb
# ---------------

  # format according to the how you set up the output of Job::jobs_due_soon 
  # and Job::jobs_completed.
  #
  # see second example for suggestions on how to iterate over data of
  # dynamic length in the table.
```

## Place logic for the data into the controller:

```
# jobs_controller.rb
# -------------

  def dashboard
    @table_one_data = [job.name, job.number, job.due_date, job.progress]
    @table_one_body = jobs_due_soon
    @table_two_data = [job.number, job.name, job.cut_at]
    @table_two_body = jobs_completed
    render :dashboard
  end

# dashboard.html.erb
# ------------------

  <%= render 'table', row_data: @table_one_data, table_body: @table_one_body %>
  <%= render 'table', row_data: @table_two_data, table_body: @table_two_body %>


# _table.html.erb
# ------------------

  # format according to how you set up the output of Job::jobs_due_soon and 
  # Job::jobs_completed
```

Comment: I appreciate the solution, but I would prefer to take a different approach as this violates separation of MVC by putting display logic into the controller.

Comment: I can see how you could make a case for that. Updated my answer.